# How to determine whether to use "with whomever" or "with whoever"

Tags: whoever-vs-whomever

In these sentences, should I use whoever or whomever?

I'm going to the park with whomever/whoever.
I'm going to the park with whomever/whoever I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. But please note that your question is  a variant on the "who" vs "whom" question which has been asked multiple times, and is therefore a duplicate question.

Comment: And different people have already given different answers.

Comment: I think the who vs whom question is similar. But when you add a with whomever vs with whoever...the rules might be different. didn't really get this http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp